# wkhtmltopdf fails on Azure Website

Tags: azure, wkhtmltopdf, azure-web-app-service

I'm using the https://github.com/codaxy/wkhtmltopdf wrapper to create a pdf from a web page on my website (I pass in an absolute url e.g. http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/PageToRender.aspx It works fine in dev and on another shared hosting account but when I deploy to an Azure website it fails and all I get is a ThreadAbortException.
Is it possible to use wkhtmltopdf on azure, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
This simple example just using Process.Start also doesn't work. It just hangs when run on Azure but works fine on other servers.

```
string exePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\App_Data\\PdfGenerator\\wkhtmltopdf.exe");
string htmlPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\App_Data\\PdfGenerator\\Test.html");
string pdfPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\App_Data\\PdfGenerator\\Test.pdf");
StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
using (var process = new Process())
{
    using (Stream fs = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} -", htmlPath);
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
        while (!process.HasExited)
        {
            process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Comment: We're having troubles running wkhtmltopdf on a hosting environment running on Windows 2012 Server. In case it helps, you can read the error the page spits out at this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zAk5Fn7V)

Comment: No. It seems you can't do this on azure websites. We used a workaround with a wpf service running on another host.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this SO question regarding a similar issue.  This guy seems to have gotten it to work.  RotativaPDF is built on top of wkhtmltopdf hence the connection.  I am in the process of trying it myself on our Azure site - I will post in the near future with my results.

[Azure and Rotativa PDF print for ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940431/azure-and-rotativa-pdf-print-for-asp-net-mvc3)

Comment: I ended up going a different route - www.html2pdfrocket.com.  This is an API that you can call and worked great for us.  The only issue was I had to use absolute URLs so they API can find all the page's resources.  This works well with Azure as there are no references to add to your project.  Their website above has some good examples.

Comment: After hours of headaches with this, ended up trying www.html2pdfrocket.com and got it working in like 30 min! Thanks! (8 years later lol)